# Fourier transform of a sum of chirps

Tags: fourier-analysis

A chirp signal is defined as follow:
$$x(t)=\sin(\omega t^2)$$
I have the following modified chirp:
$$y(t,N)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sin(\omega t+k\beta t^2)$$
My problem is to find the Fourier transform $Y(\Omega,N)$ of $y(t,N)$.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat standard being a Gaussian integral. You will have
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\Omega t}\sum_{k=1}^N\sin(\omega t+k\beta t^2)dt.
$$
This reduces to the evaluation of the two integrals
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\Omega t\pm i(\omega t+k\beta t^2)}dt.
$$
Now, complete the square in the exponent as $\left[\pm\sqrt{k}\beta t+\frac{(\Omega\pm\omega)}{2\sqrt{k}\beta}\right]^2-\frac{(\Omega\pm\omega)^2}{4k\beta^2}$ and you are left with
$$
   e^{i\frac{(\Omega\pm\omega)^2}{4k\beta^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\left[\pm\sqrt{k}\beta t+\frac{(\Omega\pm\omega)}{2\sqrt{k}\beta}\right]^2}dt.
$$
Finally,
$$
  e^{i\frac{(\Omega\pm\omega)^2}{4k\beta^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\beta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\tau^2}d\tau=e^{i\frac{(\Omega\pm\omega)^2}{4k\beta^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\beta}(1-i)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
$$
Turning back to your sum, you are done.